# Android appcompat v7 error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Being new to Android developent I followed the simplest of tutorials, built a new android project, accepting all default settings (built it for kitkat). To my dismay I have an un-planned project - `appcompat_v7`,  along with the errors:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Users...\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'

and twice the following

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Is there a quick way to fix these?
Is this a sign of how difficult, and bugged with unpleasant surprises learning Android is going to be?

(Hope it will not be similar to learning IOS 6 years ago...)

Comment: Do you have appcompat_v7 support library available? If it is already available (you can check that in sdk manager - extra section), you can get the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19842241/2449067. Otherwise, using SDK manager, first download the support library, then follow the steps from the previous link.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `appcompat_v7` library is added by default to an Android project. You will most likely need it for any demo projects you start making.

To correctly add this library, follow these steps:

**For Android Studio**:

**1.** Ensure that you have the [**Android Support Repository**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#download) installed in your [**SDK Manager**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html):

[image]

**2.** In your `build.gradle` file, include the following `implementation` statement

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

within the `dependency` bracket.

**3.** Perform a Gradle sync with the `Sync Project` button.

---

~**LEGACY ANSWER**~:

**For Eclipse**:

The trick is, you need to clean & build the `appcompat_v7` project. Go to

```
Project -> select Clean -> select the project.
```

After doing this, if the project does not get built automatically, right click on the project in the package explorer and select `Build Project`. Now the `.jar` file will be generated in the project's `bin` folder. After that, clean & build all projects that reference `appcompat_v7`.

Now the library should be correctly referenced by all projects that need it.

**Note also that**:

- You must have the latest versions of **SDK Tools** / **Build Tools**
  / **Platform Tools**. If you try this and it doesn't work, then go to
  the Android SDK Manager and make sure you have the latest versions of
  the required tools.
- In case your project only requires API level 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich)
  & above, select API level 14 for "minimum required SDK" in the
  project wizard when you create a new project. Now the appcompat_v7
  library will not be required for this project, and the application
  will use the native ActionBar class which is present in AOSP builds
  from ICS onwards.

**Further References**:

**1.** [**How to add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878804/3287204).

**2.** [**Android actionbar how to add supporting library v7 appcompat for Eclipse**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903778/3287204).

**3.** [**android-support-v7-appcompat library project won't work**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19841657/3287204).

**4.** [**Difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and android-support-v4**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271695/3287204).

Comment: Probably most answers are correct but this did it for me.

Comment: The error you mentioned occurs when the `.jar` file in the `/bin` directory of a Library project is deleted ...

Comment: You saved my life.

"You must have the latest versions of SDK Tools / Build Tools / Platform Tools."

This trick resolved my problem. I have all updated Tools except "Build Tools". So I just update the "Build Tools", restarted eclipse then clean "appcompat" project and found my problem is solved. -Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked for me but only after I'd installed the latest Java JDK (which was a solution to the problem detailed here [Android - "Parsing Data for android-21 failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474298/android-parsing-data-for-android-21-failed))

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your SDK manager

click ur sdk manager icon in the ecilipse then update **android support Repository** in the extras

then

go to File->import->existing project

> abt bundle->sdk->extra->android->support->v7 to workspace

after import v7 to workspace go to lib folder choose both jar and right click and choose build to workspace then again right click v7 project go to java build path choose the checkbox and click apply and ok..

if u have updated sdk then follow this steps

**step 1:**

Right click ur project then go to

> property->choose java build path

**step 2:**

click Add External jar

**Step 3:**

Browse to ur adt bundle go to ur workspace choose the folder

> android-support-v7-appcompat -> lib -> appcompat_v7.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried all of mentionded above advices and much more from, but no one helped me to solve my issue. My solution was creating a progect with minimum required SDK **API 14: Android 4.0 (IceCreamSandwich)**. Doing this way Eclipse will not create appcompat_v7 project.

Also I found another, better, solution:

1. Go to **Android SDK Manager** and install **Android 5.0.1 (API 21)** or newer. If you don't use the emulator you can install only *SDK Platform* and *Google APIs*;
2. Go to **appcompat_v7** -> **Properties** -> **Android** and check *Android 5.0.1* in the **Project Build Target**;
3. Then go to **Java Build Path** -> **Order and Export** and check *Android 5.0.1*;
4. Do the same procedure for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Appcompat_7 error solved!

Hi, im a complete beginner, i solved my problem by go to SDK manager update/install all the new *android sdk build tools* (as im not sure which is which i should update/install so i update/install all the build tools. after updated/installed all the new build tools i closed my eclipse and relaunch the eclipse again. if you see any error again? go to the top bar click *PROJECT* and choose *CLEAN*. and run your application again and i think it will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me when i changed project build tarjet to API 21 for the android_support_v7_appcompact project

Answer (score 0):

Strange fix but this worked for me ( My minimum SDK for my project is 10 - can't use 14)

1. Right-click on the "appcompat_v7" project and go to 
   -> Properties -> Android.
2. Your target build should already be set at the latest build (in my case  Android 5.0.1). Click any other android package (apart from its current target) and click "Apply". Click "Ok" to close the box.
3. Re-open the Properties box by the same method but this time check the latest build (in my case Android 5.0.1) as the Project Build Target. Click "Apply", then "Ok" to close the box.
4. Clean the appcompat_v7 project. You'll probably need to clean/build all other projects that reference this library.

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having with same Issue and fed up but finally I got the answer . I resolved this by Copy appcompat library E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat and paste appcompat Library in the the Project which I want to Import . I close the Eclipse and reopen. But One thing I want to consider before these stuff I updated Android Support Repository and Android Support Library as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading the file manually somewhere on the internet (be careful) and putting it into the needed `\appcompat_v7\bin\` folder **before** creating a new Android project. After that, also my `R.java` file was generated successfully.

Honestly, no other way seemed to fix it. Could not obtain the file via the SDK manager.