# Unable to find "appcompat" library at "android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat"

Tags: android

Currently I'm facing the following issue--

"***No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.***" To solve this issue I'm following answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light), but I found there is no "appcompat" library at "android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat". But in my SDK manager it is showing that "Android Support Library" is installed. See the following screen

[image]

Thank you..!

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096639/3292795

Comment: did u checked this folder `abt bundle->sdk->extra->android->support->v7`

Comment: @prabhakaran Yes I have checked it, but there is only one folder "gridlayout".

Comment: **gridlayout** ?? i think you are checking wrong folder.. or else clean your project and restart your workspace

Comment: @prabhakaran No, I'm checking at correct path "D:\DateADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\extras\android\support\v7"

Comment: your `android support library` api level is 12. you need to update that

Comment: right click your workspace and then choose `android Tool` then choose `add support library`

Comment: @prabhakaran  I am facing same issue... have you got solution?

Comment: @Namo I have same issue like you... have you got working solution?

Comment: delete the installed Android support Library and reinstall again using sdk. You can see the updated appcompat.