# Android SDK Content Loader has encountered a issue. parseSdkContent failed

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

After trying to update the ADT plugin and download Android 5.0 SDK, I got the error:
"Android SDK Content Loader has encountered a problem.
parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR17Y.png

I removed Eclipse, Android SDK, ".android" and workspace folders.

I downloaded the new Eclipse (4.4.1), ADT plugin (23.0.4.1468518) and Android SDK (only 5.0 API 21):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjECP.png

Create new empty project and I got the same error.

What should I remove it to look clean?

**Updated:** I installed everything on a clean OS, but I got the error.
Any solutions, please.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26474299/3640790) helped me to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to [AOSP Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77726) this bug caused by rendering library.
To solve it:

1. Download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W);
2. Go to /platforms/android-21/data folder;
3. Rename layoutlib.jar (for backup purpose);
4. Copy the same file from your android-20 folder to this folder;
5. Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, delete Android 5.0 (API 21) in Android SDK Manager and restart Eclipse.

It work in my case.

Even re-install Android 5.0 (API 21).

- **SDK Platform**
- A system image for the emulator, such as **ARM EABI v7a System Image**

Comment: Yes, if do not use Android 5.0 there are no errors.
But if I use a Android 5.0 in project, I get an error :( 
I have deleted and downloaded all over again many times. I even reinstalled JDK.
I'm thinking already reinstalled OS. 
I download from SDK [only this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cjECP.png)
I have never run the emulator and downloaded AVD images. Should I download the ARM EABI v7a System Image?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but on updating the **Sdk platform** for **Android 5.0**, the error vanished.