# android-support-v7-appcompat/bin missing in Android Dependencies

Tags: android

I think the title describes the problem. I have already followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229189/appcompat-does-not-work) , added appcompat as a library in my project.But still getting this error. What can I do?

[image: Android Dependencies]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem. I am giving it here. May be it will help somebody.

In my project I needed appcomat_v7 support library. I added appcompat_v7 support library correctly as [instructed here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#). But still it was showing that error. Its because appcompat_v7.jar was missing from */android-support-v7-appcompat/bin folder as android-support-v7-appcompat project was not building properly and creating that jar file. It was happening because of this [Parsing Data for android-21 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474298/android-parsing-data-for-android-21-failed) error. I have installed JDK 1.8.

Then clean & build appcompat. This time appcompat_v7.jar was created. Then clean & build my project. And it worked!