# Eclipse Android Graphical Layout Not Showing Anything

Tags: android, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

I don't know why am getting this error. 
I tried changing the java version and still didn't work.

Anyway resolving this problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky2TX.png

Comment: install new `API 22` from `SDK manager`

Comment: Eclipse is no more supported

Answer (score 0):

You need install JDK 1.8 and set the java compiler to 1.8
Also can check this link for same issue.
[Android - "Parsing Data for android-21 failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474298/android-parsing-data-for-android-21-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager and install Android 5.1.1 (API22). Make sure you are connected to the internet. After installation, restart the SDK Manager and see if there are any Updates available.