# Please solve appcompat_v7 error

Tags: android-support-library, android-appcompat

My Android Support Library is properly installed by SDK Manager.
Using this [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) I doing this procedure.
Selecting Adding Library with recources - Using Eclipse > doing these procedure.
After I finish, created "android-support-v7-appcompat" file in Eclipse.

android-support-v7-appcompat > res > values-v21 > styles_base.xml >

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
       parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
</style>
```

this line creating with error. How I can fix this problem?
I read some question about appcompat_v7 error but I can not fix it yet.
Please tell me effective way to solve it forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the android-v4 jar file under the libs folder,and add it from the android-support-v7-appcompat libs folder. I had this problem before,and I found it so annoying!

Comment: You mean add new android-v4 jar file from android-support-v7-appcompat libs folder?
I did it just now, but error still have

Comment: look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841657/android-support-v7-appcompat-library-project-wont-work

Comment: yes this is how i fixed it. You should also do the following in case that you haven't. File->import->.....sdk->extras->android->support->v7->appcompat.

Comment: and after that do a clean and hopefully you will be fine.

Comment: Yes I did it and it works after I changed Project Build Target from Android 4.3.1 to Android 5.0.
Question: How I can create the project for the Android 4.3.1 without error?

Answer (score 0):

If in console the error is

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'

, on android-support-v7-appcompat library project choose *Properties/Android/Project Build Target* and set checkbox on Android 5.0 to solve.