# after copy and paste of an application , appcompat_v7 gives error while configure "build path"

Tags: android

I have created an application , due to some system issue I copied one application in a D:\backup folder. Again I copied this application on Desktop and tried to import but System gives an Error (Red cross) once I am trying to add Library . Main problem is when I remove and add library ,system shows D:/backup/appcompat_v7. Even there is no existence of "backup" folder. I Goggled a lot but not getting any satisfactory suggestion. Any kind of help get appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

appcompat_v7 should not be directly inside /backup/ no? Copy your appcompat library jar file in the folder where you want to save it. Then 'Add External Jar' (Properties>JavaBuildPath>libraries) and browse to this folder to add appcompat.

Comment: Thanks @Poutrathor , I did the same as you said. But nothing worked for me. Still I am having with same problem. I added jar from my current workspace but  again its shows Red cross

Comment: We will need screenshot or precise description of your set up :/

Answer (score 0):

Simply I copy a fresh "Running project" from my another Desktop. Once I Import that project its Shows Error in R due to appcompat path
[image]

Comment: Finally I Got the Answer. I Copy appcompat Library from E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat  and paste it in to my Current Project which I wish to Import . Close the eclipse and Open . I follow this Link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841657/android-support-v7-appcompat-library-project-wont-work/19842241#19842241 . Thanks