# Cant include appcompat_v7 in library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a new in Android Development and I am having some issue about the **R.java** file. And I read some suggestions that in order to generate this file you shouldn't have any error on the XML file. In my case I fave an error in my styles.xml

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.`

And also this:
`ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type`

And I read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar) that I need to reference the AppCompat but when I checked on my settings the AppCompat has an error.

[image]

I already updated my SDK tools with the latest one

[image]

And also can you help me how can I solve the problem in the R.java. What I know is it is auto generated but in my case it doesn't generate even I start a new project.

Can you help me with this? So that I can continue my study. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are new to Android, I strongly suggest that you use Android Studio. Google will no longer support the ADT plugin for Eclipse. Also, Android Studio, and more specifically Gradle, make it easy to manage library dependencies, especially for the appcompat libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I used Eclipse over Android because I found many resources using Eclipse and I already purchased a book that using Eclipse :-(. Can you suggest me where can I find some tutorials from basic to advance using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, you will find a **lot** of online resources and books that describe using Eclipse for Android Programming. It has been the primary IDE for Android for many years. Android Studio has been in Beta for several years and was released as version 1.0 less than six months ago. Most of the official documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/index.html has been updated to Android Studio. It is a good place to start.

Comment: Eclipse has been primary IDE for Android for many years but is no more. So if you find a tutorial for Eclipse it's probably going to use obsolete libraries/tech/etc. Stay away from that stuff. There's an official free online course https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853

Comment: Possibly this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533084/3002851